# Two issues I'm having with my site. One is CSS, one is Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

**First** off, my CSS issue is probably simple, but after 20+ minutes of fiddling, I just can't seem to figure it out. Here is my site:

[www.phlbombers.com](http://www.phlbombers.com)

If you click through the pages, you'll notice the h2 heading for each page is in the same spot, except for the "stats" page. Since I added a selector and an h3 heading above the selector, the h2 heading of "stats" moved down, and I can't get it back in place.

**Second** is the selector I added. I want to use javascript to do the following, but don't know how to do it.

Upon hitting the page "stats", the most current season is brought up on the page. You can select a season from the drop down menu, and upon selecting it, it will then show that seasons stats.

Im assuming it would be coded something like this (psuedocode)

Selector:
option 1 connected to Div 1 (season 1)
option 2 connected to Div 2 (season 2)
option 3 connected to Div 3 (season 3)

Upon going to the "stats" page, The current season (div 1) would automatically show up (would be cumbersome to have to have it show nothing and have to select the current season). Previous seasons would be within Div 2 and Div 3 (each div, one season) and selected from the drop down menu. When a option is selected, the correlating div to that option is the only thing that shows till you select another option.

I put in the very very basic starting for it, but I haven't found anything to really hit on what I am doing, and haven't been able to put together the pieces to do it myself.]

```
<form method="get" action="javascript:void(0)">
        <select id="seasons" name="seasons">
            <option value="season1">2015/16 Winter</option>
            <option value="season2">2015 Summer</option>
            <option value="season3">2014/15 Winter</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

JS: (im fully aware it makes no sense, I don't really understand what I'm doing.)

```
function changeSeason(){
    var id = document.getElementById("seasons").selectedIndex;
    var season = document.getElementById("seasons").options[id].value;
    document.getElementById("") = season;
}
```

Comment: Two questions should be posted as two separate questions. Also, markup in the first question needs to be posted here since your site may go away one day rendering the answer useless to others.

Comment: @Barmar, I see.  Removed my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the first CSS issue. Wrap those with a div's with a float. In mobile devices you need to remove those floats.

```
<div style="float:left;"> <h2>Stats</h2></div>
<div style="float:right;"><h3 id="select">Select a season:</h3>
    <form method="get" action="javascript:void(0)">
            <select id="seasons" name="seasons">
                <option value="season1">2015/16 Winter</option>
                <option value="season2">2015 Summer</option>
                <option value="season3">2014/15 Winter</option>
            </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: Here is the result after adding those div's]

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
Simply drag your h2 to the first child place of the div.

[image]

Question 2:
  In form create an extra option: All
  Add every season a class="visibility" with a simple css: display:none;
  and toggle that class with selection.

Comment: That put it above, thanks.

Comment: h2 tags should always be before h3 tags, and any header should be before it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the CSS part of your question:

add `position:relative;`to the `.col2`rule and change the following rules like this:

```
#col2 #select {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    float: none;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

#col2 form {
    padding-right: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Or you could pack these two elements in another div together and apply `position: absolute;` and `right: 0px;`to that one.